# Context menu plugin and how to make a right click availble on tablets?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

We are using a great context menu plugin https://vaadin.com/directory/-/directory/addon/vaadin-context-menu in our Vaadin based app. Now we are trying to figure out, how to make it usable on tablets (touch devices in general). Is there a way how to 'simulate' right click on tablets? Is there anyone who solved this for VAADIN context menu plugin?

Comment: Have you tried with a long-tap?

Comment: Tried on iPad with Chrome, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such implementation for the long tap listener.

You probably have to create your own custom component or create a vaadin component extension with a client side counter part. GWT has the support for touch events and Vaadin got some helper classes you need (like hooking pointer events).